# Zend_Form and decorators : how to insert html tags on a multi options radioform?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I'm currently trying to use Zend_Form, and it's decorators mechanism, in order to output some well formated HTML, but I don't manage to have the wanted output.

Concretely, I have a radio button form element (Zend_Form_Element_Radio), with a multiple option registred in it, like this:

```
$codeHolder = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('radiobuttons');
$codeHolder->setLabel('Title');
$codeHolder->addMultiOptions(array( 1       =>  'Label1',
                                    2       =>  'Label2',
                                    3       =>  'Label3'));
$codeHolder->setValue('depart');
```

Here is the wanted HTML output:

```
`<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="label1[radiobuttons]" id="id1" value="1" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="label1[radiobuttons]" id="id2" value="2" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="label1[radiobuttons]" id="id3" value="3" /><</td>
</tr>`
```

I have turned in many ways the problem, but I don't see any solution. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Your wanted HTML output looks strange, is this really what you want to achive? Empty label tag, name "label" in the name attribute?

Comment: oops, I've modified the HTML: I don't want any label !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use a personalised view helper to render the right HTML markup.

[This article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450), about Zend_Form and helpers has really helped. A must-read !